# How to use Layered architecture of spring and still follow object oriented structure?

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-mvc, open-source

I learned spring and its layered structure(controller,service and dao)

```
@Controller("userController")

@service("userService")
@Transactional(     propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,     isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT,      readOnly = true)

@Repository("userDAO")
```

Now I am confused how do I make use of **good OOPS practices** (like [this](http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs211/ATMExample/)) with these layered structure to make a big project( real world have more complex business logic then sample applications usually provided). I also want to use these spring transaction and other features provided by framework. 
Can some please help me out with it or refer to open source project which clarifies my doubt.

Comment: After all spring is using OOPS concepts only (Inheritance, abstraction). So don´t worry, you will be using them in MVC structure. Regarding your @Controller...., etc., they are only the annotations not the new concepts. They are also a part of JDK.

Comment: And the code under all classes (Controller or Service or dao), you will write using core java concepts only.

Comment: Rajnikant I agree spring is using OOPS concept only, but according to OOPS not every thing can by divided under those layers.

Comment: But its a conventional way to divide the work flow in three layer : Model (dao, pojos), View (JSP, html, emails, templates), Controller (This will only handle request where to redirect). So old or new developer will have idea what will be where. Like business logic will only be at service layer only. If he want to see if I do this request then where I will be directed then he will search in controller layer. Same way, he will implement the things accordingly. Getting me?

Comment: There are multiple open source projects available you can start with Spring petclinic project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic to understand the MVC architecture with the Spring.

Comment: See the edit to my answer with an example project

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**In nutshell**

Layered architecture will just ease the code maintainability and consistence when it becomes huge and complex.

The fact to remember is that to do a proper software design before doing the implementation.

- Encapsulation - Business logic specific for a domain model should go inside it.
- Abstraction - Segregate the interfaces according to the grouping of services while writing the common business logic in the abstraction.
- Inheritance - Use when you are drafting your domain objects
- Polymorphism - Along with inheritance when you want to change the business logic of child models.

---

**In detail**

Below I'm trying my best to provide an example of an ERP application for this discussion. Hope an ERP is a sufficient **big project** to view the business logic complexity.

The below description is for any developer who need an idea to understand and make use of layered project structure in Spring (or any other framework).

*But please note these are not rules to be followed but the best practices to be utilized. :)*

---

**1. Data Access Layer - Model /Domain Objects**

This contains the mapping of actual tables to classes.

> In an ERP example, this is where you get the models: `CustomerOrder`, `CustomerOrderLine`
>
> This also contains the en-capsuled logic of child domain objects and the domain logic of self. For example, the `CustomerOrderLine` is a child of `CustomerOrder`. The child cannot exists without the parent. So the parent will have the full control of building the childs within it. ie **Business logic encapsulation.**. ie: `Add CustomerOrderLine`, `RemoveCustomerOrderLine` etc.. And when it comes to self domain logic,  `ApproveCustomerOrder`, `RejectCustomerOrder` etc..

---

**2. Data Access Layer - Repository**

This contains nothing but simple CRUD to database with `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE SQLs`. You can use repository pattern in Spring along with `Spring Data JPA`.

**Key note: do not write any complex logic in this layer unless your logic is highly data intensive**

In that case you might have to write one or more functions to do complex query statements. (Preferably in `JPQL`)

> In an ERP example, this is the place you write logic for `GetCustomerOrders`, `GetCustomerOrderByCustomer`, `GetCustomerOrderLines`, `GetOrderByStatus`
>
> In simple terms this layer defines how the application will communicate with the outside entities such as Database.

---

**3. Service Layer**

This is the place where **you should put your complex business logic which involved Multiple unconnected (not child - parent) domain models**. These will be reused in Web Controllers and Rest API Controllers.

So to maintain the consistence and to **implement the security**, I would prefer all the business logic even which were written in the domain models gets wrapped up at this layer.

> In the ERP exmple this is the place you write the logic or wrap the logic which is written in Domain Model. For example `CreateCustomerOrder`, `ListCustomerOrder`, `ApproveCustomerOrderLine`, `ReleaseCustomerOrder`,...

*In case if these logic should get executed along with other model logics, then those should be called at sequence within service layer as well. For example.*

**Misc Examples on complex business logic**

> If you want to create a `Purchase Order` for your supplier, when the `Customer Order` is released.

Then, this can be done by creating a service called `SupplyChainService` binded using Spring AOP to the `CustomerOrderService.ReleaseCustomerOrder`. In microservice design this can be done by a event published by `Supply chain` domain microservice to a queue and get consumed by `Customer Order` domain microservice

---

**4. Controllers**

Controllers can be categorized in two, namely: Web Controllers, and REST Controllers. No business logic should be implemented in this layer because the same logic can be required to call in Web as well as in API level.

> In the ERP system, this is the place where you will write the controller for your customer order form to enter data and save it to create a new customer order.
>
> This will be the place you will also create a API controller like REST to create the customer order via a mobile application or from a windows client.

*Thanks to the SO community who showed me areas that I didn't cover on OOP principles in this answer*

**Edit**

---

*This is an answer when microservice is not too mainstream. Though it answered the OOP concepts, also look into CQRS based design as it's more common in modern micro service based architecture. Either way, you can incorporate OOP concepts regardless of what software architectural pattern you use.*

Comment: I could not understand the OOP part on the solution. For me, you are describing a SOA aproach only, where the Services are responsable to have the business logic (instead of a class Object).

Comment: @Dherik - "This answer explains layered service architecture while using the OOP principles." - what OOP principles?

Comment: Just so I don't have to guess, what does ERP refer to?  Maybe the answer could include a brief overview of the example application.

Comment: If the http layer returns models which are different to the database/repository models, where should the orchestration between these two occur? It doesn't seem right that the service using the repository should know about the http endpoint models. If this were split into two service layers what would they be called?

Answer (score 10):

I think, you are asking a wrong question here. Layered architecture is inherently not object-oriented, and  therefore, while using (some of) the object-oriented practices with it would be possible or even advisable, it should not by itself be the goal. It is akin to asking how do I use best truck driving practices to ride a bike.

Why am I saying that layered architecture is not object oriented? Well, as we know, there are three principles that distinguish object-oriented design: encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism.

While the last two may or may not be present, depending on your design choices, layered architecture is, pretty much, the *opposite* of encapsulation: by nature of this approach, you explicitly separate your data ("DTOs") from your logic ("services").

Don't get me wrong, the fact that this approach isn't object-oriented doesn't mean that there is anything wrong with it. And vice versa, "object-oriented" isn't synonymous with "good", it's one of many tools in a programmer's toolbox, and, as with any tool, is better suited to solving some problems than others.

Layered architecture is a good design pattern, that can be successfully used to solve many real-life engineering problems. It has it's own set of best practices that can and should be used, and while that set may have some intersections with its counterpart from OOP, the two are certainly not equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

Spring application design and OOD are not mutually exclusive.

The typical Spring (MVC) application has the following structure:

1. One or more `@Controller`classes. These are the entry points of your application. They should not contain any business logic. Despite the name I identify them as the **V** in MVC ([Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))
2. One or more `@Service` classes. This is where you develop your business logic (BL). One of the benefit in putting your BL here is that it can be reused by multiple controllers (by a `@Controller` and by a `@RestController` for example). They are the **C** in MVC.
3. One or more `@Repository` classes, where you implement your persistence layer (database, in-memory, whatever...). Additionally you can implement a set of `@Component`s classes that describe your domain objects. These are the **M** in MVC.
4. Other classes that you can't map in the MVC pattern, like `@Configuration`, `@ControllerAdvice` and other Spring configuration/management classes.

While designing each of these objects, you can follow whatever [OOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design) approach you like.

In the OOD example you mentioned, I would design my application like this:

1. One view (`@Controller`) for each actor
2. One `@Service` for each use case
3. One `@Repository` and one `@Component` for each domain class

EDIT: you can find an example project I wrote for university [here](https://github.com/ferrarimarco/uniroma2/tree/master/is-web-app). It implements what I explained in the last three points with an additional layer (between @Controller and @Service) because there was a requirement to minimize dependencies on the **C** layer. The concepts still apply.

Comment: @NirbhayMishra I have added a link to a GitHub project you can refer to

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to understand two different concepts that can interoperate together.

**Layered Architecture**

Layer architecture is one of the architecture styles of the industry.  In this we have separate layer to do specific logic. Example we have presentation layer, business layer and data service layer.  This is called horizontal slicing of the application. There are other architectural styles like Service Oriented/Component based architecture where the application is sliced vertically.

Lets suppose you have automated reservation process.  Normally if you go with the layered architecture design (horizontal slicing) then we have different layer to do the job required. But when it comes to the vertical slicing then we identify different entities of the application as Reservation, Customer Management, Fund Management. We will implement these components and they intercommunicate to build our reservation application. The point to remember here is internal component can fallow the same layered architecture.

**OOPS Concepts**

OOPS concepts helps you design the application in the object oriented manner.  Once you identified the architecture style then you have to implemented the application in an extendable manner that can be easily maintained. So, they different implementation methodologies . OOPS is on of them. It suggest some of the design principles that helps you to implement the applications in a better way

See [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))