# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method list() from the type EmployeeDAO

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing an application in eclipse to display a database table in a web page using Spring and hibernate. The following is my DAO file.

```
package net.codejava.spring.dao;
import java.util.List;
import net.codejava.spring.model.Employee;
public interface EmployeeDAO {
public List<Employee> list();
}
```

and the controller i have created is

```
package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import antlr.collections.List;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.*;
public class HomeController {
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView listEmployee(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
    List<Employee> listEmployee = EmployeeDAO.list();
    model.addObject("listEmployee",listEmployee);
    model.setViewName("ome");
    return model;
}

}
```

Now its showing an error message in my controller like "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method list() from the type EmployeeDAO".

How to resolve this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `EmployeeDAO` by `@Autowired` annotation in your controller.

It's better define service layer and use it in controller. I think you should have more info about layers. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429832/how-to-use-layered-architecture-of-spring-and-still-follow-object-oriented-struc)

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public ModelAndView listEmployee(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
   List<Employee> listEmployee = employeeDAO.list();
    model.addObject("listEmployee",listEmployee);
    model.setViewName("ome");
   return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 way use Dao class in autowired reference for creating object in controller.

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
```

otherwise use static method in dao class.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue:
you have to ensure you are using lowercase when calling your method, meaning:
instead of EmployeeDAO.list();  you have to use:   employeeDAO.list();