# [Spring boot migrate to 2.3.3]InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For queries with named .. you need to use provide names. Use @Param for query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Getting below error after upgrading spring boot from 1.x to 2.2.2 which has inherently upgraded Hibernate too.

For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.

**Error Trace.**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at
```

**Method declaration with query**:

```
@Query(value = "select * from DocumentInfo where ClientID=:clientID and siteID=:siteID  and processStatus=:processStatus and eXcelProcessStatus=:eXcelProcessStatus order by modifiedDate asc /*#pageable*/ ", countQuery = "select count(*) from DocumentInfo order by DocumentInfoID /*#pageable*/ ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DocumentInfo> findByClientIDAndSiteIDAndProcessStatusAndeXcelProcessStatusOrderByModifiedDateAsc(int clientID, String siteID, String processStatus, String eXcelProcessStatus, Pageable p);
```

**Hibernate versions** :

hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar

**Probable workaround:**
i know by adding `@Param (name="")`  to each parameter in method will work but that is something which i don't want as it was working in earlier version of hibernate/spring boot.

Strange is even though in following

```
@Query(value = "from ExcelColumnMapping where eXcelMapping=:eXcelMapping")
    List<ExcelColumnMapping > findByExcelMapping(ExcelMapping eXcelMapping);
```

i am not using the native query still it says please use the @Param which was working without specifying @Param in earlier version of hibernate.

**Edit 2**

The issue seems to be with the Spring-data-jpa and not hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven can you please try to add this to your dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also add this before the properties tag in your pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

Don't forget to add below statement to your application.properties file to avoid hibernate bugs:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: @ViralKondhia Do you still get the same exception?

Comment: @14239812  Yes the same exception

Comment: @ViralKondhia Would you mind adding the method you have on your Controller?

Comment: @14239812  Controller ? i am using spring jpa and if you mean repository method its already added. (Two examples are there.)

Comment: @ViralKondhia For it to work properly you should have controller and service classes as well. At least this is the suggested format. You can check the approved answer on this link to understand it better: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429832/how-to-use-layered-architecture-of-spring-and-still-follow-object-oriented-struc)

Comment: @ViralKondhia Tbh I think the problem is the way you are calling it. I have no idea how you are using the declarations without a proper structure and I can't possibly help without seeing the code. Best of luck.

Comment: @14239812 As i mention it is due to the upgrade of Spring boot as it was working earlier.